# Skipping some axis labels in a plot with imagesc

Tags: image, matlab, plot, heatmap, label

I have created a big heat map using matlab's `imagesc` command. It plots the error output for each combination of the values in x and y axes. As can be seen in the figure there are too many axes labels. This might become even denser as I plan to increase the number of points in both x and y axes - which means I will get more outputs on a finer grid.

I want to be flexible with the labels, and skip some of them. I want to do this for both X and Y. I also want to be flexible with the "ticks" and draw either all of them or maybe skip some of them. Keep in mind that both the X and Y values are not increasing in order, at first the increment is 0.01 for 9 points, then 0.1, then 1 or 3 or whatever. I will change these increments too.

I tried to show what I want the graph look like in the second image. I want roughly the labels shown in red boxes only. As I said these are not set values, and I will make the increments smaller which will lead to denser plot.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

OS: Windows 7, 8 (64 bit)

Matlab version: Matlab 2014 a

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the ticks and labels like this:

```
ticksarray=[1 33 41 100 ...] % edit these to whatever you want
tickslabels={'1', '33', '41', '100'; ...} % match the size of both arrays

set(gca,'XTick',ticksarray)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',tickslabels)
```

The same thing applies to the y-axis.

---

Small working example:

```
x=1:100;
y=2*x.^2-3*x+2;

plot(x,y)

ticksarray=[1 33 41 100];
tickslabels={'1', '33', '41', '100'};

set(gca,'XTick',ticksarray)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',tickslabels)
```

[image: resulting graph]

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
figure(1)
load clown

subplot(211)
imagesc(X);

subplot(212)
imagesc(X);
h = gca;
```

Now you can either set a maximum number of labels per axis:

```
%// define maximum number of labels
maxLabel = 3;
h.XTick = linspace(h.xlim(1),h.xlim(2),maxLabel);
h.YTick = linspace(h.ylim(1),h.ylim(2),maxLabel);
```

[image]

or define how many labels should be skipped:

```
%// define number of labels to skip
skipLabel = 2;
h.XTick = h.XTick(1:skipLabel:end);
h.YTick = h.YTick(1:skipLabel:end)
```

[image]

---

You can also get a different number of ticks and labels, more complicated though:

```
maxLabel = 3;
maxTicks = 6;
h.XTick = linspace(h.xlim(1),h.xlim(2),maxTicks);
h.YTick = linspace(h.ylim(1),h.ylim(2),maxTicks);
h.XTickLabel( setdiff( 1:maxTicks, 1:maxTicks/maxLabel:maxTicks ) ) = repmat({''},1,maxTicks-maxLabel);
h.YTickLabel( setdiff( 1:maxTicks, 1:maxTicks/maxLabel:maxTicks ) ) = repmat({''},1,maxTicks-maxLabel);
```

---

If you use a prior version of Matlab 2014b, then you will need the `set` command to set all properties:

```
%// define maximum number of labels
maxLabel = 3;
Xlim = get(h,'Xlim');
Ylim = get(h,'Ylim');
set(h,'XTick', linspace(Xlim(1),Xlim(2),maxLabel));
set(h,'YTick', linspace(Ylim(1),Ylim(2),maxLabel));

%// or define number of labels to skip
skipLabel = 2;
XTick = get(h,'XTick');
YTick = get(h,'YTick');
set(h,'XTick', XTick(1:skipLabel:end));
set(h,'YTick', YTick(1:skipLabel:end));

%// or combined
maxLabel = 3;
maxTicks = 6;
Xlim = get(h,'Xlim');
Ylim = get(h,'Ylim');
set(h,'XTick', linspace(Xlim(1),Xlim(2),maxTicks));
set(h,'YTick', linspace(Ylim(1),Ylim(2),maxTicks));
XTickLabel = cellstr(get(h,'XTickLabel'));
YTickLabel = cellstr(get(h,'YTickLabel'));
XTickLabel( setdiff( 1:maxTicks, 1:maxTicks/maxLabel:maxTicks ),: ) = repmat({''},1,maxTicks-maxLabel);
YTickLabel( setdiff( 1:maxTicks, 1:maxTicks/maxLabel:maxTicks ),: ) = repmat({''},1,maxTicks-maxLabel);
set(h,'XTickLabel',XTickLabel);
set(h,'YTickLabel',YTickLabel);
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention I use matlab 2014a. So should I use set command for each of your "h." noation you used. ?

Comment: I see that in 2014b they have significantly changed the structure, it seems more intuitive now. However I use 2014a and have to deal with 'set', as you have pointed out. If you have time could you post the same solution above (all) for version 2014a. I would greatly appreciate it. I have figured out most of it but just want to make sure.

Comment: Based on ypur 2nd solution this is what I did for 2014a Matlab version, and it worked fine: 

skipLabel = 2;

%%
xtick = get(h, 'XTick')
set(h,'XTick', xtick(1:skipLabel:end))

ytick = get(h, 'YTick')
set(h,'YTick', ytick(1:skipLabel:end))

Answer (score 0):

After applying the second method proposed by @thewaywewalk I got the second figure below. Apparently the labels need to be structured as well, because they only take the first so many labels.

[image: The figure from imagesc]

[image: The figure after applying the skiplabel method]

Then I tried to manipulate the labels as shown below, and got the third image.

```
            skipLabel = 2;
            XTick = get(h,'XTick');
            YTick = get(h,'YTick');
            set(h,'XTick', XTick(1:skipLabel:end));
            set(h,'YTick', YTick(1:skipLabel:end));

            XTickLabel = get(h,'XTickLabel');
            labelsX = cell( length(1: skipLabel:length(XTick)) , 1);
            j = 1;
            for i = 1: skipLabel:length(XTick)
                labelsX{j} = XTickLabel(i, :);
                j = j + 1;
            end
            set(h,'XTickLabel', labelsX);

            YTickLabel = get(h,'YTickLabel');
            labelsY = cell( length(1: skipLabel:length(YTick)) , 1);
            j = 1;
            for i = 1: skipLabel:length(YTick)
                labelsY{j} = YTickLabel(i, :);
                j = j + 1;
            end
            set(h,'YTickLabel', labelsY);
```

The Y axis labels seem to be in place as before (right next to tick), however the X axis labels seem to be shifted to the left a little. How can I correct this?

Another note: How can I change the scientific values into normal numbers? Also, probably there is a better approach at manipulating the labels.

[image: After changing the labels]